# how to handle base tag target attribute in iphone uiwebview to open new window

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

When the links are supposed to open a new window, iphone uiwebview won't trigger an event when user click these links. We had to use javascript to do some trick to the target attribute of the links.

I can handle 'a' tag to open in the '_self' window with the trick without problem. But when I do it the same way with the 'base' tag. it doesn't work.

I believe the base target is set by the javascript. But **the base tag is in the head, which may be handled by the uiwebview before my javascript executed, so the target change may not reflected in the webkit engine**.

Could someone please give some suggestion, so I can open the link in the same uiwebview?

The following is the sample HTML opened in the uiwebview

```
<html>
<head>
<base target='_blank'>
</head>
<body>
<a href='http://google.ca'>google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the code to be executed in the

(void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView*)webView

```
static NSString* js = @""
    "function bkModifyBaseTargets()"
     "{"
            "var allBases = window.document.getElementsByTagName('base');"
            "if (allBases)"
            "{"
                "for (var i = 0; i < allBases.length; i++)"
                "{"
                    "base = allBases[i];"
                    "target = base.getAttribute('target');"
                    "if (target)"
                    "{"
                        "base.setAttribute('target', '_self');"
                    "}"
                "}"
            "}"
    "}";
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"bkModifyBaseTargets()"];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feature detect opening in a new window/tab(target=\_blank) with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647014/feature-detect-opening-in-a-new-window-tabtarget-blank-with-javascript)